# Parse data and fit in Hash gives not expected result

Tags: arrays, perl, hash

I have data which need to be parsed and print on the screen.

Here is the data and my script:

Input Data:

```
__DATA__
Node : Network=Europe,Network=Ireland,Node=S01,Sec=1
Ref : [Network=Europe,Network=Ireland,Node=S01,SecAnt=1]

Node : Network=Europe,Network=Ireland,Node=S01,Sec=1,Car=1
resBy : [Network=Europe,Network=Ireland,Node=S01,Cell=1]

Node : Network=Europe,Network=Ireland,Node=S01,Sec=1,Car=2
resBy : [Network=Europe,Network=Ireland,Node=S01,Cell=1]
```

Script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict; use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

use List::Util qw /uniq/;

my ($node, $item, %hash1, %hash2, %hash3);

while (my $line = <DATA>){
    chomp $line;

    if ($line =~ m/^\s*Node :\s*(.*?)(,Car=\d+)?\s*$/) { 
        $node = $1;
    } elsif ($line =~ m/^\s*Ref :\s*\[*(.*?)\]*\s*$/) { 
        $hash1{$node} = [ split /, /,$1 ] ; 
        ($node, $item) = "";
    } elsif ($line =~ m/^\s*resBy :\s*\[*(.*?)\]*\s*$/) {
        $hash2{$node} = [ split /, /,$1 ]; 
        ($node, $item) = "";
    }
}

foreach my $sec (keys %hash1){
    foreach my $ant (@{$hash1{$sec}}) {
        push @{$hash3{$ant}}, $sec;
    }
}
print "Hash3:\n". Dumper(\%hash3); 

my $i = 0;
foreach my $sec_ant (sort keys %hash3){
    ++$i;
    print "sec_ant_$i:$sec_ant\n";
    print "car_$i:", join('###', uniq @{$hash3{$sec_ant}}), "\n";
}
```

This is my current output:

```
Hash3:
$VAR1 = {
          'Network=Europe,Network=Ireland,Node=S01,SecAnt=1' => [ 
                          'Network=Europe,Network=Ireland,Node=S01,Sec=1'
          ]
};
sec_ant_1:Network=Europe,Network=Ireland,Node=S01,SecAnt=1
car_1:Network=Europe,Network=Ireland,Node=S01,Sec=1
```

Expected result:

```
Hash3:
$VAR1 = {
          'Network=Europe,Network=Ireland,Node=S01,SecAnt=1' => [
                 'Network=Europe,Network=Ireland,Node=S01,Sec=1,Car=1', 
                 'Network=Europe,Network=Ireland,Node=S01,Sec=1,Car=2',
          ]
};
sec_ant_1:Network=Europe,Network=Ireland,Node=S01,SecAnt=1
car_1:Network=Europe,Network=Ireland,Node=S01,Sec=1,Car=1###Network=Europe,Network=Ireland,Node=S01,Sec=1,Car=2
```

Since it should look for a `Node` value without `Car` data, and pick the respective `SecAnt` data. And Based on the `Node` value the corresponding `Sec+Car` data(from `hash2`) needed to be picked by the use of `resBy`'s `Node` data. How can I do that?

Comment: Can you explain how the `resBy:` entries are relevant for the output?

Comment: @clamp Its nothing to do with in this case. Its been used in other scenario.

Comment: So how does _needed to be picked by the use of resBy keyword line._ apply?

Comment: @clamp your question makes sense. I have corrected it.

Comment: Will your actual dataset include other nodes? If so, does '_Based on the Node value_' refer to the value `Node=S01` or does it refer to the data assigned to `$node` in your code example?

Comment: @clamp: The dataset would contain other nodes as well. And yes, only change we can see is in `Node=S01`. Maybe it could be `S02` or `S03` etc. But I need the entire set of value in `$node` variable.

Comment: A longer dataset would help with comprehensive answers, because otherwise we're trying to infer the structure of your data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can I suggest making use of `$/` as a record separator? It'll make this task easier. I think you're overcomplicating things with your compound conditionals. How about:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;
use List::Util qw /uniq/;

my %results;

#current 'parent' node
my $current;

#parse input as paragraphs - blank line delimited. 
$/ = '';
#iterate the data - we don't bother setting `$line` because it's not necessary
#as all data is extracted via pattern matches against implicit $_      
while (<DATA>) {
    #if we're a Ref stanza, set the current node. 
    if (m/Ref : (.*)/) {
        $current = $1;
    }
    #if we're a resBy stanza, insert the node into the parent
    #using push, so we don't overwrite. 
    if (m/resBy/) {
        m/Node : (.*)/;
        push( @{ $results{$current} }, $1 );
    }
}

print Dumper \%results;


my $count;
foreach my $sec_ant ( sort keys %results ) {
    ++$count;
    print "sec_ant_${count}:$sec_ant\n";
    print "car_${count}:", join( '###', uniq @{ $results{$sec_ant} } ), "\n";
}

__DATA__
Node : Network=Europe,Network=Ireland,Node=S01,Sec=1
Ref : [Network=Europe,Network=Ireland,Node=S01,SecAnt=1]

Node : Network=Europe,Network=Ireland,Node=S01,Sec=1,Car=1
resBy : [Network=Europe,Network=Ireland,Node=S01,Cell=1]

Node : Network=Europe,Network=Ireland,Node=S01,Sec=1,Car=2
resBy : [Network=Europe,Network=Ireland,Node=S01,Cell=1]
```

We're using `$/` to set 'paragraph' mode, so each iteration of the while loop is blank line delimited.

We extract from each record the 'Node' details, and then match `Ref` or `resBy` to decide what to do with the rest of the node - treating a `Ref` node as a parent (and setting `$current` each time we encounter one) and a `resBy` as a child, to push the value into the `$current` branch of the hash.

This produces the output requested:

```
$VAR1 = {
          '[Network=Europe,Network=Ireland,Node=S01,SecAnt=1]' => [
               'Network=Europe,Network=Ireland,Node=S01,Sec=1,Car=1',
               'Network=Europe,Network=Ireland,Node=S01,Sec=1,Car=2'
                                                                  ]
        };
sec_ant_1:[Network=Europe,Network=Ireland,Node=S01,SecAnt=1]
car_1:Network=Europe,Network=Ireland,Node=S01,Sec=1,Car=1###Network=Europe,Network=Ireland,Node=S01,Sec=1,Car=2
```

You indicate there's additional data - I've just tried to infer what the rest of your data might work like, so this could be wrong.